# Problems with Tensorflow module

Tags: python

I have a problem with Tensorflow after `import tensorflow`

Two errors backwards I get :

> 2020-10-02 15:13:07.794919: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could
> not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror:
> libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory 2020-10-02 15:13:07.794937: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart
> dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

My System:

> OS: Debian 10.6 AMD Ryzen 3 3300X Radeon XFX RX 590
> python 3.7
>
> tensorfolow 2.3.1
>
> IDE PyChram 2020.2

I read that the GPU and CPU version of Tensorflow are together? Can I use this with my graphics card?

Comment: TensorFlow only supports Nvidia GPUs, so you cannot use a Radeon GPU with it. You might want to try ROCm

Answer (score 1):

You say "I get two errors". But the second message says "Ignore above cudart dlerror". You only get a single error, and the second part says that the error really should have been a warning.

This is just a bad warning message. The real warning is that your GPU won't work with Tensorflow, but the CPU code will.